# Creating a delta variable over time for different values of an ID

Tags: r, dataframe, difference

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Year <- c("2004", "2004", "2004", "2005", "2005", "2005", "2006", "2006", "2006")
Province <- c("0101", "0102", "0103", "0101", "0102", "0103", "0101", "0102", "0103")
Price <- c("1,02", "1,50", "1,70", "1,25", "1,56", "1,78", "1,32", "1,65", "1,88")

Data <- data.frame(Year, Province, Price) 

Year Province Price
2004 0101     1,02
2004 0102     1,50
2004 0103     1,70
2005 0101     1,25
2005 0102     1,56
2005 0103     1,78
2006 0101     1,32
2006 0102     1,65
2006 0103     1,88
```

I am now trying to create a variable that depicts the differences in prices to the previous period for each province. The prefered outcome would be:

```
Year Province Price Diff_Price
2004 0101     1,02  NA
2004 0102     1,50  NA
2004 0103     1,70  NA
2005 0101     1,25  0,23
2005 0102     1,56  0,06
2005 0103     1,78  0,08
2006 0101     1,32  0,07
2006 0102     1,65  0,09
2006 0103     1,88  0,1
```

I found a simular post froma a while ago, but this was done for only one "province" and maybe by now there are also easier solutions for this problem: [Creating a delta column to plot time series differences in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552334/creating-a-delta-column-to-plot-time-series-differences-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be to use `dplyr::lag` (and `readr::parse_number` for the conversion to a numeric).

```r
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)
library(readr)

Data |> 
  # Convert to proper numeric
  mutate(
    Price = readr::parse_number(Price, locale = readr::locale(decimal_mark = ","))
  ) |> 
  group_by(Province) |> 
  mutate(Diff_Price = Price - lag(Price, order_by = Year)) |> 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 9 × 4
#>   Year  Province Price Diff_Price
#>   <chr> <chr>    <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1 2004  0101      1.02    NA     
#> 2 2004  0102      1.5     NA     
#> 3 2004  0103      1.7     NA     
#> 4 2005  0101      1.25     0.23  
#> 5 2005  0102      1.56     0.0600
#> 6 2005  0103      1.78     0.0800
#> 7 2006  0101      1.32     0.0700
#> 8 2006  0102      1.65     0.0900
#> 9 2006  0103      1.88     0.100
```

Answer (score 3):

You can group by `Province` and make a `diff`erence:

```r
with(Data, ave(Price, Province, FUN = \(x) c(NA, diff(x))))
```

Or in `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
Data %>% 
  group_by(Province) %>%
  mutate(Diff_price = c(NA, diff(Price)))
```

---

Note that you should first convert your prices to `numeric` format by replacing the comma with a dot:

```r
Price <- c("1,02", "1,50", "1,70", "1,25", "1,56", "1,78", "1,32", "1,65", "1,88")
Price <- as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", Price))
```

Answer (score 2):

In Price convert the commas to periods and to numeric using `type.convert` and then use `diff`.

```
library(dplyr)

Data %>%
  mutate(Price = type.convert(Price, as.is = TRUE, dec = ","),
         Price_Diff = diff(c(NA, Price)), .by = Province)
```

giving:

```
  Year Province Price Price_Diff
1 2004     0101  1.02         NA
2 2004     0102  1.50         NA
3 2004     0103  1.70         NA
4 2005     0101  1.25       0.23
5 2005     0102  1.56       0.06
6 2005     0103  1.78       0.08
7 2006     0101  1.32       0.07
8 2006     0102  1.65       0.09
9 2006     0103  1.88       0.10
```

Here is a base solution

```
Data |>
  transform(Price = type.convert(Price, as.is = TRUE, dec = ",")) |>
  transform(Price_Diff = ave(Price, Province, FUN = \(x) c(NA, diff(x))))
```

### Note

There were errors in the input data code lines in the question so we used this

```
Year <- c("2004", "2004", "2004", "2005", "2005", "2005", "2006", "2006", "2006")
Province <- c("0101", "0102", "0103", "0101", "0102", "0103", "0101", "0102", "0103")
Price <- c("1,02", "1,50", "1,70", "1,25", "1,56", "1,78", "1,32", "1,65", "1,88")
Data <- data.frame(Year, Province, Price)
```

Comment: This looks very promising. The variable was first a character, so I turned it into a factor. When I turn it into a numeric, it cuts of all the digits with the first code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Year <- c("2004", "2004", "2004", "2005", "2005", "2005", "2006", "2006", "2006")
Province <- c("0101", "0102", "0103", "0101", "0102", "0103", "0101", "0102", "0103")
Price <- c("1,02", "1,50", "1,70", "1,25", "1,56", "1,78", "1,32", "1,65", "1,88")

Data <- data.frame(Year, Province, Price)

# Replace comma with a decimal point
Data$Price <- gsub(",", ".", Data$Price) 

# Convert Price to numeric
Data$Price <- as.numeric(Data$Price) 

Data <- Data %>%
  arrange(Year, Province) %>%
  group_by(Province) %>%
  mutate(Diff_Price = c(NA, diff(Price))) %>%
  ungroup()

# Print the Data dataframe
print(Data)
    Year  Province Price Diff_Price
  <chr> <chr>    <dbl>      <dbl>
1 2004  0101      1.02    NA     
2 2004  0102      1.5     NA     
3 2004  0103      1.7     NA     
4 2005  0101      1.25     0.23  
5 2005  0102      1.56     0.0600
6 2005  0103      1.78     0.0800
7 2006  0101      1.32     0.0700
8 2006  0102      1.65     0.0900
9 2006  0103      1.88     0.100
```